# Looking for a server/proxy that can dynamically route requests to back-end servers depending on client's IP

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

When a request comes to the proxy/server, depending upon the requester's IP, the request will be routed to a specific back-end. It is a requirement of the system that the proxy needs to get the destination back-end IP from a central key-value store.

I have tested nginx for this but *proxy_pass* needs to be static and couldn't find a way to achieve this goal.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need a load balancer with sticky load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to make queries to the key-value store from nginx. Nginx LUA module could be helpful with this, however I don't know if it can be used to access key-value stores.

Another alternative is to forward all requests to a PHP script, which fetches the value from key-value store and then forwards the request to the proper backend.